# Marking/dragging do not work after upgrade from 16.04 to 16.04.2 for some trackpad buttons

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, mouse, touchpad

I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.04.2 (had not done updates in a while).
I also use the 4.8 kernel that comes with 16.04.2.

I'm using a Dell Latitude E7440, which has two sets of mouse buttons above and below the trackpad. The lower buttons work, only the upper buttons do not work correctly:
All operations that involve holding the left touchpad button down stopped working, e.g. marking text, drag&drop etc.

Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: What update commands did you run, did you do `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: No, just apt upgrade.

Comment: It really seems to be touchpad-related, as my other input device (this little cursor in the middle of my Dell keyboard works).